# How to setup Microsoft Access as a POS system for 3Dcart?

Tags: ms-access, content-management-system, e-commerce, point-of-sale

I'm helping out with an 3Dcart eCommerce/online store doing basic web administration tasks analyzing their data. Their POS system is manged manually with Excel at the moment, and so updating information has become pretty time consuming.  I want to know if it's possible (and if so how) to connect/integrate 3Dcart's database system and be able to use Microsoft Access for the programming in order to be able to merge tables/databases more seamlessly and work more efficiently.

Is this possible? Are their any online resources that show how to integrate Microsoft Access as a POS system (with 3Dcart specifically if possible) or could anyone describe how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

3dcart allows you to import your products using the Import/Export feature from a CSV file. But it seems like there is no way to make it work with Access automatically. Also I've found this service http://www.file2cart.com/shopping-cart-data-import-options/6265-import-excel-to-3dcart
Maybe it will be helpful for you. And finally you can contact these guys [Smart POS](http://posvt.com/) and ask them for help.